# CString move optimization like in std::string

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

Is there a technique to move the internal buffer of a CString in an another  one hence avoiding a deep copy.

I have an output CString which is the result of parsing an InputString, I would like to exchange the buffer of both strings.

```
void ProcessString(CString& strInputString)
{
CString strOutputString
//...
strInputString = strOutputString; // how to avoid a deep copy
}
```

Comment: Is this question based on analysis, or just assumes that there were a deep copy? I believe that `CString` implements copy-on-write semantics, so `strInputString = strOutputString;` merely increments the reference count on `strOutputString`, without copying any data. A few more questions: Have you identified a performance issue, or is this just premature, guess-based optimization? Have you considered the natural implementation, that returns a `CString`, and automatically benefits from RVO? Why is `strInputString` an in/out parameter anyway?

Comment: @IInspectable I assume that there is a deep copy, I can check assembly code to be sure of it... I need to optimize the process of strInputString as it's a user request (a keyword) and I want to avoid that ProcessString takes too much time as my application is used by many users. I just need to prefix some characters in strInputString by a backslash that's why I need a temporary string to do this stuff. It's preferable to swap the buffers of both strings (input and output) instead of copy, this is feasible with STL string and I don't know it it is the same case with the good old CString

Comment: Have you profiled the code? It doesn't sound like it. You are trying to optimize something, where you `1` don't know, if it is a bottleneck, and `2` if it were, you'd have no idea whether your changes improved performance, or degraded it. Or didn't have any effect. You need to profile first. With that out of the way, neither `std::string` nor `CString` support **pre**pending a character, without making a copy. Complexity of that operation is O(n).

Comment: P.S.: Looking at assembly doesn't tell you anything about performance. A profiler will. And why look at assembly at all, when you have full source code for MFC at your disposal?

Comment: There is no deep copy in this case.  IInspectable is right. CString has a copy-on-write semantic. And your code may only free the old contents of strInputString and than increment the usage count of strOutputString. Only if strOutputString or strInputString is changed later a new buffer will be allocated.